# Flat UI - Bootstrap 3 - Dropdown not working properly

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, select, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just switched to Bootstrap 3 and the Flat UI Framework and I am now trying to add 'select' element to my website with Bootstrapp Select but I am facing some issues.

The element has the correct style and respond properly when I click on it however if I click right below the select element it still changes the value of my input. Basically everything happens as if the dropdown was collapsed except I cant see it.

HTML:

```
 <select id="tk_groupbundle_tgrouptype_currency" name="tk_groupbundle_tgrouptype[currency]" required="required">
 <option value="1">Euro</option>
 <option value="2">US Dollar</option>
 <option value="3">British Pound</option>
 <option value="4">Indian Rupee</option>
 <option value="5">Australian Dollar</option>
 <option value="6">Canadian Dollar</option>
 <option value="7">Swiss Franc</option>
 <option value="8">Chinese Yuan Renminbi</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
$("select").selectpicker({style: 'btn', menuStyle: 'dropdown-inverse'});
```

CSS:

```
nothing except:

    <link href="/web/flat-ui/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="/web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Have you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a file named "template.html" in the downloaded Flat UI package. Put your markup there in the file and everything should go smooth. I think you have some missing .js include files.

Also your Flat-UI .css file must come after bootstrap .css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to Flat-UI-Pro-1.2.5. I was having the same issue but as soon as I upgraded it fixed it. Seems as if there was a bug.